# What is the evaluation order for JSX in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have the following components:

```
const Cell = (props) => {
    const { cellData } = props;
    console.log("--START--")
    console.log(cellData);
    console.log("--END--")
    return <div>cellData</div>;
};

const Col = (props) => {
    const { cell } = props;
    console.log(cell);
    return (<div>    </div>);
}
```

Doing something like

```
    const col = (<Col 
        cell={<Cell />}
    />);

    const content = (
        <div>
            {col}
        </div>
    );
```

Seems to run the code in Col first. But if props is just a function parameter, shouldn't it run the `<Cell />` part first that was passed in?

Comment: I think the poor console logging in the function body of the component may be confusing you (they should all be logged in an `useEffect`), but a react component needs to render out its children before it's considered "rendered".

Comment: The [React implementation notes](https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html) might help shed a light on why.

Comment: Drew Reese is right, but I believe the confusion comes from the fact that `<Cell />` isn't calling render at all. React is calling render while navigating through the elements tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth this is a trivial matter to test. What you see and what you ask about are two sides of the same process.

## Issue

When you console log in the body of a functional component this is done as a side-effect.

[image]

The function body of a functional component is essentially the equivalent of a class-based component's `render` method. In other words, the *entire* function is the "render" method. React "renders" each component as part of the reconciliation process to compute a diff from any one render cycle to the next. Note also that the "render" function is to be considered a pure function, free of any side-effects, like console logging or any other asynchronous behaviors.

You ask about the "evaluation order" and what you *think* you should see is the "render order". In other words, React must evaluate the component tree from the top down, in a depth-first traversal, but it renders to the DOM from the bottom up. It needs to have fully processed all children in any subtree to compute a diff *of* that subtree.

In React we generally do not care about anything until a component is mounted and usable as this is when the component can "work with the DOM, run side-effects, and schedule updates". This is why mounting order is generally more important than evaluation order. Evaluation can be "paused, aborted, or restarted" by React.

With the provided code, modified to console log when the component is rendered into the DOM:

```
const Cell = ({ cellData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Cell MOUNTED");
    console.log("--START--");
    console.log({ cellData });
    console.log("--END--");
  }, []);
  return <div>{cellData}</div>;
};

const Col = ({ cell }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Col MOUNTED", { cell });
  }, []);
  return <div>Col: {cell}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const col = <Col cell={<Cell cellData="hello world!" />} />;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <div>{col}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image]

You can see that the child component `Cell` is rendered first before the parent component `Col` logs that it is mounted.

```
Cell MOUNTED 
--START-- 
{cellData: "hello world!"}
--END-- 
Col MOUNTED 
{cell: Object}
```

[image: Edit what-is-the-evaluation-order-for-jsx-in-react]

Part of rendering a component is fully rendering out its subtree of children components. All children need to be rendered first. It is impossible for it to work any other way or in any other order. If React didn't have this deterministic order then it'd be impossible to diff the rendered DOM result from one render cycle to the next.

Comment: `All children need to be rendered first` - You've come to the wrong conclusion because you are using `useEffect` - [if you remove the `useEffect` part](https://codesandbox.io/s/what-is-the-evaluation-order-for-jsx-in-react-forked-m6dhx?file=/src/App.js), the parent obviously has to be rendered before a child can rendered, because the parent may choose **not to render** a child - no point for the framework to render the child if the parent isn't going to render it anyway. I feel like I may have misunderstood something in your explanation, however.

Comment: @Adam Review the [React Component Lifecycle](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) and note that the function body of functional components ***is*** the "render" method and where render is called... during the "render phase". Note also that this should be a pure function free of side-effects, like console logging anything. The "render phase" is often conflated with the component being rendered, i.e. when it is committed to the DOM during the "commit phase", where `componentDidMount` or the initial `useEffect` callback are called.

Comment: @Adam You are correct that React starts *processing* the Parent first, OFC, since it necessarily needs to know what children it has to recurse on them, but again, this is all processing that happens during the "render phase" and ***not*** during the "commit phase". The "evaluation" order is top-down, while the "render"/mounting order is bottom-up. If it's easier just think of React rendering as a Depth-First traversal. We don't generally care about anything until a component is mounted and usable.

Comment: I understand what you’re saying now, but, at least to me, what you’re describing does not answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw out a simple answer to this:

> Seems to run the code in Col first. But if props is just a function parameter, shouldn't it run the  part first that was passed in?

The answer is no.

Consider this: React has no way of knowing what `Col` is doing with the cell prop. What if `Col`'s implementation looked like this:

```js
const Col = ({cell}) => {
   const [canRender,setCanRender] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setTimeout(() => setCanRender(true),1000:
     return () => clearTimeout(timer);
   },[]);

   return <div>{canRender ? cell : null}</div>
}
```

React would waste time and effort calling `Cell` when `Col` isn't even going to render it immediately (or possibly ever).

Just to put a real fine point on it for the OP:

**React only evaluates (e.g. calls) a component once it has been returned from it's immediate parent's render.**